# Proving NP completness without reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, proof-techniques, np

What methods are there to prove a language is NP-complete? I already know the reduction method, but are there more sophisticated/advanced methods to prove this?

Comment: Since NP-completeness is *defined* in terms of the reduction, probably not. But there *may* be.

Comment: @Raphael: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment: showing that a problem is NP complete can be done by reducing to a *single* NP complete problem. However, the process has to start somewhere! In particular, you need to know that there is at least *one* NP-complete problem. Historically, this problem was "The language of Turing machines that halt in a given polynomial time for all input". It was shown that *every* NP problem is reducible to this one, and that this problem was reducible to SAT.

Answer (score 5):

To prove that a problem is **NP**-complete, you must show that it's in **NP** and that every problem in **NP** reduces to it.  As far as I'm aware, there are only really two ways of doing the latter:

- show that some problem already known to be **NP**-complete reduces to your problem;
- show directly that every problem in **NP** reduces to your problem by showing that your problem can essentially simulate a nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing machine.